# Como exibir a versão do meu site em todas as páginas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web.config

Eu quero exibir no rodapé de todas as minhas páginas a versão em que meu site esta rodando.

Por exemplo: Versão 1.0

Depois que eu fizer uma atualização no meu site e publicá-lo novamente seria algo tipo Versão 2.0

Qual a melhor maneira, ou a mais indicada, de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recomendo você colocar no web.config uma propriedade com o número da versão do site.

E exibi-la na MASTER.PAGE.
No web.config

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="versaoSITE" value="2.0"/>
</appSettings>
```

No rodapé da master page.

```
<label><%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["versaoSITE"].ToString();%></label>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.